# How to set the proportion of a bar(in y-axis) in a mpandroidchart barchart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I just started learning to code and develop for Android.

Right now, I'm trying to make something like this:
[Project Fi App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkwOq.jpg)
However, I cannot find a parameter or method in the MPAndroidChart library to set the proportion of a bar in a BarChart(or a HorizontalBarChart that I'm using). The bar in the BarChart simply decide its proportion automatically. What I want is a fixed maximum range of the Y-axis, and the proportion of the bar in the graph change according to its value.

Another problem is that I cannot get rid of the label on each bar. I wrote

```
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

but the Bar still have a value to the right of it.

A screenshot of the fragment that contains the BarChart:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgMxX.png)

Here's the full code

```
public class MainFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
public MainFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> vals = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    BarEntry val = new BarEntry(0.20f,0);
    vals.add(val);

    BarDataSet setTime = new BarDataSet(vals,"time used");
    setTime.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    setTime.setColor(R.color.colorAccent);

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    xVals.add("1");

    BarData data = new BarData(xVals, setTime);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.getContext(),R.color.chartBackGround));
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
    barChart.setDescription("");
    barChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(1.0f,barChart.getAxisLeft().getAxisDependency());

    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(1.0f);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);

    barChart.invalidate();

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Here's my color.xml

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#607d8b</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#455a64</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#64ffda</color>
<color name="windowBackground">#ffffff</color>
<color name="chartBackGround">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorTransparent">#00ffffff</color>
```

Thank you for helping!! I really cannot find the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(maxValue);
```

This should give you a fixed max value.

If you want to get rid of the labels, try:

```
setDrawLabels(false)
```

This method can be applied to either of the axes, depending up on which labels you want to skip.

All the information you need is available in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki).

EDIT: Use this to get rid of the values

```
setTime.setDrawValues(false);
```

In your comments, you also asked how to change the color of the dataset. For that, use this:

```
setTime.setColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the label problem isn't solved...The label is on the bar, not the axis. I tried and it didn't work. Just curious, why did you declare another YAxis object to set the maxValue? Can I write barChart.getAxisLeft.setAxisMaxValue()?

Comment: Yeah you can definitely use `barChart.getAxisLeft`. This is just another way of doing it. Regarding the problem of the labels being on the bar, can you possibly share a screenshot of what it looks like and maybe some code as well.

Comment: If your problem isn't solved yet, then please provide more details. If it is solved, then please consider accepting the answer so that this question can be removed from the unanswered questions list.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I just edited the question, and included the full code and a screenshot(the screenshot is in the link, as I'm not allowed to embed a picture yet). Another problem in here is that, even I set the color of the entire dataSet to colorAccent, which is cyan, the graph is still using the default color.

Comment: Check edit to get rid of those values. I also added an edit to set the color. Let me know if that doesn't work either or if you have any other problem.

Comment: The setDrawValues() worked. I changed the parameter in the setColor() to Color.CYAN, and it worked. However, I didn't understand why this worked and what I used didn't. The method takes a color represented by an int, and both Color.CYAN and R.color.colorAccent are colors represented by ints, and I made sure that the R.color.colorAccent is indeed specified in the color.xml   `<color name="colorAccent">#64ffda</color> `

Comment: If you could share your `color.xml` file, I could look in to it. However, I just tried setting a color in my `color.xml`, and referenced it in setColor(), and it worked just fine. In any case, if your original problem itself is solved, please accept the answer.

Comment: I marked it as answered :) Sorry, I'm still learning to use this site... see my color.xml above in the edited question.

Comment: No worries! If you still face problem with R.color reference, please post another question with the code for color.xml. I'm sure that I or someone else would be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the color problem on my own. It turns out that I have to pass the actual color int to the `setColor()`method by using`ContextCompat.getColor()`, instead of giving it something like `R.color.colorAccent`which is also an int but only an id reference.